# How this wildcard is working?

Tags: unix, wildcard

I am getting confused between following wildcard characters

1. [:upper:]
2. [[:upper:]]

Please explain how following commands are working?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`[:upper:]` means "one of the characters of *:*, *u*, *p*, *e*, or *r*." Your first example finds the one thing that ends in *e*.

`[[:upper:]]` means "one of the characters in the `upper` class." Your pattern matches the one thing that ends in an upper case letter.

Your third example matches anything with at least one upper case letter in it.

From `bash(1)`:

```
          Within  [  and  ],  character classes can be specified using the
          syntax [:class:], where class is one of  the  following  classes
          defined in the POSIX standard:
          alnum  alpha  ascii  blank  cntrl  digit graph lower print punct
          space upper word xdigit
          A character class matches any character belonging to that class.
          The  word character class matches letters, digits, and the char-
          acter _.
```

Note the "Within [ and ]...the syntax [:class:]..."

Comment: Thank you so much Rob. It was really helpful.